# What is written on the last ATP finals trophy?

Tags: trivia, tennis, atp, awards

I was wondering what do they write on these trophies, what material they are made of too. Couldn't find this in Internet.

[image: ATP trophy]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This trophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_Finals#Points,_prize_money_and_trophies) made by silversmiths [Thomas Lyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Lyte) is [made up of Silver](http://www.bbc.com/news/business-20759536).

> "Winners of major sports tournaments, such as tennis' ATP World Tour, are invariably rewarded with enormous silver trophies."

Logo at the bottom of trophy:

[image: trophy b]

And the text written on it is "***[THE BRAD DREWETT TROPHY](http://www.espn.in/tennis/story/_/id/9435603/atp-honor-brad-drewett-renamed-trophy)***<sup>[1](http://www.tennisworldusa.org/tennis/news/ATP_Tennis/11100/tennis-atp-names-seasonending-championships-trophy-after-late-chief-brad-drewett/)</sup>" with previous year winners.

The trophy [is named The Brad Drwett Trophy in honor of the ATP executive chairman and president](http://www.espn.in/tennis/story/_/id/9435603/atp-honor-brad-drewett-renamed-trophy) [Brad Drewett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brad_Drewett), who died from Motor Neurone Disease (also known as ALS or Lou Gehrig's Disease).

[image: names]
[(Source)](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/p14-tennis-a-20141118.jpg)

[image: names 2]
[(Source)](https://financialtribune.com/sites/default/files/field/image/17january/16_dimitrov.jpg)